# copy images from iOS device's Photos app to my own app's directory using NSFileManager's copyItemAtURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to copy images from Photos app to my own app using copyItemAtURL method of NSFileManager.  And I got the error 262 and by looking up to Apple's, it says "NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError = 262"

Question:  have anyone been using this method?  Is this something not allowed?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because Photos stores the pictures in a folder inaccessible from your app's sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure what you're doing to produce that specific error code, I can tell you that you're likely going down the wrong path to get pictures out of the Photos app.  What you want to do is to use the [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) with the source type of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html).

Comment: Some how I misunderstood that controller before I started design my own way of presenting the images user interface.  Which i finally got it working the way i planned.  Now I am still undetermined which way to go with.  Do you know the differences between UIImagePicerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary and UIImagePickerContrllerSourceTypeSavedPhotoAlbum?  (I have never used an iPhone and only have an iPad 2 for a little while)